# Hitting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" despite using '&'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace values in a column based on two filter conditions. Despite using `&`, I am getting the following error:

> "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous".

This is what I have tried:

```py
df = db.pd.DataFrame({"Fruits":["Apple","Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange"],\
                     "Year": [2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012], \
                     "Price": [2,3,1,1,2,3]})
df["Change"] = ""
df["Change"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Increase" if (x['Price'] < df.loc[(df["Year"]+1 == x['Year'])\
                & (df['Fruits'] == x['Fruits'])]['Price']) else '', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.any()` which returns `True` if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False. So, in your case it will identify all instances for which your conditions are `True` and assign `Increase` to the value of the column `Change`.

Do this instead:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Fruits":["Apple","Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange"],\
                     "Year": [2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012], \
                     "Price": [2,3,1,1,2,3]})

df["Change"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Increase" if ((df["Year"] == x["Year"]-1) & (df["Fruits"] == x["Fruits"]) & (df["Price"] < x["Price"])).any() else "", axis=1)
print(df)
```

which gives

```
   Fruits  Year  Price    Change
0   Apple  2010      2          
1   Apple  2011      3  Increase
2   Apple  2012      1          
3  Orange  2010      1          
4  Orange  2011      2  Increase
5  Orange  2012      3  Increase
```

Comment: Thanks! Will be helpful if you can also add a note on how df.any works here. That would perhaps help me understand why I was getting an error.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Will try and digest this. :)